# PySpark - Synapse Notebook don't throw error if dataframe finds no files

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse, azure-notebooks

I have a Synapse notebook in which I am creating a dataframe based on parquet data. I am also filtering the files, to ensure I only pickup the new files.

```
ReadDF = spark.read.load(readPath,format="parquet", modifiedBefore=PLP___EndDate, modifiedAfter=PLP___StartDate)
```

If I set the Startdate variable to something in the future, which will ensure that no files are found I am getting the following error:

> AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.

Is there a way to ignore this error? Exactly, like in ADF DataFlow the option for "allow no files found".

Answer (score 0):

The above occurs when there is no parquet file to read in the specified path.

I have given an empty directory `ok` and I got same error.

```
spark.read.load('abfss://data2@rakeshstorage2.dfs.core.windows.net/ok',format="parquet").show()
```

[image]

You are giving a future date that means its same as reading an empty directory with no parquet files in this case.

> Is there a way to ignore this error? Exactly, like in ADF DataFlow the option for "allow no files found".

**AFAIK**, spark didn't have that feature currently. One possible way to avoid this error is to use exception handling. Put your code in try block and handle the error like below.

```
readpath='abfss://data2@rakeshstorage2.dfs.core.windows.net/myparquet'
modifiedBefore='2010-06-01T13:00:00'
modifiedAfter='2024-06-01T13:00:00'
try:
    df2=spark.read.load(readpath,format="parquet", modifiedBefore=modifiedBefore,modifiedAfter=modifiedAfter)
except Exception as e:
    print("No files found with the above dates")
```

[image]